# Creating a computer display on a glass wall

Tags: display

[I dont know where in SE to post this, but someone, somewhere probably has some ideas for me]

In No Ordinary Family the wife has a computer in her lab. That computer's monitor is the wall.
As in, there is a glass wall, and somehow it acts as the screen.

[I would show a picture but I couldent fine one, anyone have links?]

*Now how would I do that myself?*

I dont really care about the user input, but I want a display like that. Is that just special effects? Or was that wall showing video really there? Do you think they used some sort of projector? I am thinking they used some sort of rear projection(projector behind the wall shining onto the glass), but then what sort of glass was that?

Comment: wouldnt that be really, really annoying to read ? background clutter distracting the eye ?

Comment: Yes and no, depends on how it is implemented. In the show it is a nice big lab with lots of whitespace. And it might be. The idea of what I am looking for is that it would be bright enough that it looks like a solid screen when turned on.

Comment: In conclusion, the people at Natural Users Interface group have done all sorts of similar stuff. http://nuigroup.com/go/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for: http://www.kingmaker.co.uk/projection%20screens.htm

You can achieve this other ways, but the cheapest is a projector and a nearly clear laminate.

look at holoscreen and holofilm

Comment: if you can't afford it and simply want a pseudo transparent effect (read NOT on a glass wall) there is also this cheap shot trick: http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-turn-your-computer-s-LCD-screen-transparent/step1/Tweak-test-crop-and-repeat/

Comment: This is probably space for another question in itself, but, Do you know of a cheap source for such material? Or a substitute? [nice hack!]

Comment: nope...best of luck on cheap stuff to do that.

Comment: Some people[article in MAKE magazine] have gotten by with shining a projector onto wax paper. For whatever reason(lots of different variables I guess), it works, as in it catches the image, but it way too cloudy looking.

Comment: Yeah, but it isn't translucent/transparent.  The different approaches are wax paper(blocks enough light to catch the projection) or the stuff I linked to (bends light from a particular angle to the expected viewing angle).  The latter is more expensive because it requires precision fabrication for any usable image.

Comment: For anyone curious, here is the like I was referring to. http://forums.makezine.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=43

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same / similar idea. I would probably embed a low-power LED-based TV with 1080p or better, extremely bright, right within the wall behind a tinted glass "window". The glass is tinted so when you turn the screen off, you don't see the TV. The wall will need to be ventilated so keep that in mind.

Cool idea. Can't wait myself to try it.

Comment: In the show the glass wall actually has another office on the other side, so embedding a tv on the other side probably wouldent work. But that would be cool too.

Comment: yup..in the show it might be done with some clear display laminate, but a similar effect is cheaper with a projector.  then required angle of incidence is 30%.  if you don't walk close to the back of the glass, it doesn't effect the display.